# Android "publishProgress" Error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

What is wrong with this class? My progressdialog is shown but stays at 0% then disappears, it never gets percentage updates

```
public class AsyncLogin extends AbstractAsync {


    public AsyncLogin(Context context, AsyncCallback mAuthcallback) {
        super(context, mAuthcallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(String... args) {
        ...
        publishProgress(50);

        HashMap<String, String> result = html.download();
        publishProgress(75);
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        this.progressDialog.setMessage(this.context.getString(R.string.please_wait_logging_in));
        this.progressDialog.show();


        publishProgress(25);
    }


    protected void onProgresUpdate(Integer...  progress)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        Log.v("max", "set progress" + progress[0]);
        this.progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap map) {
        ...
    }

}


abstract class AbstractAsync extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, HashMap>{


    protected Context context;
    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    protected AsyncCallback mAuthcallback;

    public AbstractAsync(Context context, AsyncCallback mAuthcallback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mAuthcallback = mAuthcallback;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    }


    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.loadingSomething).toString());
        //dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgresUpdate(Integer...  progress)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        Log.v("max", "set progress" + progress[0]);
        progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

The log never writes anything

Comment: what do you want it to do? what actually happens? what debugging have you done?

Comment: What's AbstractAsync? It's not part of the Android framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chance your log level is lower than verbose?

Any chance your method never reaches "publishProgress"?

Also, you are not supposed to call publishProgress in onPreExecute. The first is to be called on the backgorund thread that runs your doInBackground, the second is called by the asynctacsk mechanism before starting the bg thread.

Would you post AbstractAsync code just in case?

EDIT:

```
onProgresUpdate
```

is actually to be spelled

```
onProgressUpdate
```

Free Tip: use @Override annotation to make sure you are actually overriding something